# Lately vs Recently

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases

How to use lately and recently? For example, of these two sentences:

1. I workout regularly but lately I have been lazy.
2. I workout regularly but recently I have been lazy.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Grammatically, changing that one word doesn't make any difference because *lately* and *recently* are both adverbs with the same function at that point in the sentence. I think it would read better if you said "I *usually* work out regularly, but lately/recently I have been lazy". (The thing that bothers me about your sentences is that "workout" should be "work out" - as one word it is a noun, but you're using it as a verb phrase.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Recently* and *lately* both mean the same - "at indefinite time in the near past" - and each one of the two can be defined by using the other. So, you can say that they are interchangeable.

At the same time, it is *recently*, not *lately*, that can be used as an adjective in the attributive way to express the quality or character of the thing we are talking about.

For example, you can say "a recently injured hand" or "recently discovered lands" but you can't use *lately* here.

Also, you can't replace *recently* by *lately* in the fixed expression"until recently".

Lastly, *lately* seems more formal while *recently* can be used in every situation.

P.S. [The Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recently%2Clately&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecently%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clately%3B%2Cc0) shows that since the 1870s there has been a noticeable decline in the use of the word *lately* and a corresponding rise in the use of the word *recently*.

Answer (score 2):

Both recently and lately are similar and can often be used interchangeably. However, lately signifies that the speaker wants to discuss both the past and present and then contrast the two. Recently can also be used in the same way. However, recently can also be used simply to specify the time when something happened without implying that events in the past are needed to understand the context of current events.

For example, "I haven't been sleeping well lately" and "I haven't been sleeping well recently" are more-or-less equivalent. The speaker used to sleep well and now he doesn't. Both the past and present are equally important to understand the situation, so either recently or lately can be used.

However, you would not say "I lately met my friend for lunch." A listener would wonder "Lately? In contrast to what exactly?"

But you could say "I recently met my friend for lunch." This just tells the listener when something happened and doesn't imply that past events are important to understanding the context of current events.

If you aren't sure whether to use lately or recently, you can normally just use recently and the proper nuance will be conveyed.

Answer (score 0):

Lately refers to a repeated action."Lately, the dog has been barking." As in the dog has been barking for an extended period of time. Recently is a one time thing unless expressed contrary in the sentence. "Recently I've been thinking about getting a dog." You need to add words that explicitly state it is continuous, or it is thought to be a one time thing. "She recently had an accident" as you said. One accident in the past.